# kivy.app is not working because my computer can't find it

Tags: python, windows, mobile, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to use Kivy but it keeps saying there is no module called "kivy.app", "Kivy" is not a package even tho I downloaded it(I downloaded it from VS code command prompt).[My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmfjQ.png)

I tried defining it on the path and adding it to the same disk, but I don't know how to solve it because a lacks guidelines for Kivy.[The path to kivy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LXK0.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: If someone can't open image for some reason then it's ok image have nothing to do with my problem, just additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a Python virtual environment to develop and distribute your Kivy application, it's more reliable and should solve your problem.

1. create a Python virtual environment (go to the directory where you want to create it and open it in the terminal):

   python -m venv venv
2. activate the virtual environment (so that the terminal uses the venv's Python exe and not the machine's)

   venv/Scripts/activate
3. if the above command doesn't work, powershell script execution is disabled on your machine. to solve the problem, use the command :
   `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` then retry the command of the second step.
4. once the venv is active, install Kivy:

   pip install kivy
5. run your Kivy applications with this venv
   `python main.py` (for example) but the venv must be enabled to run main.py with this command. otherwise use `venv/Scripts/python.exe main.py` .

I hope I've helped you.